# Bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

I'm trying to write a "non-trivial" (i.e., non-identity) bijection $\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, where I define $\mathbb{N}$ to exclude $0$.

Pictorally, the map I have in mind works, sending odds to evens and evens to odds:
$$f(n) = 
\begin{cases}
n + 1 & & \text{if $n$ is odd} \\ 
n - 1 & & \text{ if $n$ is even}
\end{cases}. 
$$
The map is certainly surjective. Let $m \in \mathbb{N}$. If $m$ is even, $m-1$ is odd and a natural number, and we have $f(m) = (m-1) + 1 = m$. If $m$ is odd, then $m+1$ is even, and we have $f(m+1) = (m+1)-1 = m$.

Injectivity is tougher to prove because of the case work. Suppose $f(a) = f(b)$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$. If $a,b$ are both odd, then $a + 1 = b + 1$, so $a = b$. If $a,b$ are both even, then $a-1 = b - 1$, then $a = b$.

I really need to rule out the case where one of $a$ or $b$ is odd and the other is even. Suppose without loss of generality that $a$ is odd and $b$ is even. Then $f(a) = a + 1$ and $f(b) = b - 1$. So $a + 1 = b - 1$, so $a = b - 2$.

I don't know how to get a contradiction out of this.

Comment: If $a=b-2$, then both $a$ and $b$ have the same parity. This is the contradiction

Comment: Excellent, thank you.